# Common genes and enzymes involved in pathogen entry into host

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, gene-expression, gene, general-biology

Many microbes like Salmonella, E.coli, Legionella pneumophila etc. enter host cells via cystoskeleton remodeling of the host cell. Do all microbes follow the same path or there are any other ways for the microbe to enter the host cell. What are the most prominent and significant enzymes involved in these and what are the genes involved in the same. It's a general question as I am looking for the common genes and enzymes that most microbes employ the mechanism of cytoskeleton remodeling.

Answer (score 1):

Passing through plasma membrane by remodeling host cell seems reasonable choice but actually most of pathogen use cell's normal functions like [endocytosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endocytosis), [phagocytosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phagocytosis), [pinocytosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinocytosis) etc to enter (*well, indirectly you need actin remodeling for this also but pathogen is not doing it actively.* ). Check [this](http://www.nature.com/nrm/journal/v7/n7/full/nrm1959.html) review for some 'simple' mechanism pathogen use to enter cell. As far as your question about enzymes, there are lot of common enzymes (specially manipulating [kinases](http://jcb.rupress.org/content/195/7/1083.full)) which are important in these pathways.Pathogens use lot of [other factors](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3859125/) to exploit host. Cytoskeleton remodeling is *indirect* output of many of these signaling events. Just to put into perspective, recently hiked on social media, Ebola virus use [micropinocytosis](http://journals.plos.org/plospathogens/article?id=10.1371/journal.ppat.1001110) like mechanism to enter into host cell. Some other representative examples in following figure (Source :[Gruenberg and Goot 2006](http://www.nature.com/nrm/journal/v7/n7/fig_tab/nrm1959_F3.html) )

[image]